# select multiple photo works only once

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating multiple upload feature (for now it's only to select multiple photos) but my code only works once to select some photos. here is the flow of my application:

1. click button "select photo".
2. open default android gallery and select some photos and then click "open".
3. default android gallery closed and back to activity where "select photo" button belong.

my problem is after I pass those 3 steps and try to click "select photo" button again, my application stopped working.

here is my activity code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.upload_motif_activity)
    btnAddPhots.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { test() })
}

public fun test(){
    val i = Intent()
    i.type = "image/*"
    //i.setType("video/*");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    i.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(i, "android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"), 1)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    println("++count" + data.clipData!!.itemCount)
    val selectedImage = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(0).uri//As of now use static position 0 use as per itemcount.
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
    //        Uri selectedImage1 = data.getData();
    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, selectedImage)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    println("+++ clipdate" + selectedImage)

    var condata: Uri? = null
    for (i in 0..(data.clipData!!.itemCount - 1)) {
        val ab = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
        textView2.text = ab.toString() + "\n"
    }
}
```

strangely my logcat doesnt show any "red" warning. this is my last 8 lines of my logcat:

```
11-06 16:11:08.947 30224-30224/tigaer.inventory V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b340b63
11-06 16:11:08.947 30224-30224/tigaer.inventory V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@2333360
11-06 16:11:08.963 30224-30224/tigaer.inventory V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@63583db
11-06 16:11:08.963 30224-30224/tigaer.inventory V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@9580e78
11-06 16:11:09.170 30224-30392/tigaer.inventory D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x558a11f950 (ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with handle 0x558a0b6e70
11-06 16:11:10.161 30224-30392/tigaer.inventory D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x558a15ed50 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x558a0b70e0
11-06 16:11:15.359 30224-30224/tigaer.inventory I/System.out: ++count3
11-06 16:11:15.430 30224-30224/tigaer.inventory I/System.out: +++ clipdatecontent://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A19001
```

Comment: Is there a crash, when you try second time? Post the stack trace if so

Comment: yes it's stopped working when i try the second time. sorry i am new in android studio. where i can find "stack trace" ?

Comment: at the bottom of AS you will see logcat. If the app is crashing, it will print some lines in read which can be used to analyze the reason for crash.

Comment: can you add the crash logs too ?

Comment: ah after i try again multiple times, i realized the error appears when i select only one photo. the error caused by this code "println("++count" + data.clipData!!.itemCount)". it works fine if i select more than one photos. how to fix this?